# How should i use Array.slice in a variable?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to upload csv file and display it on Table.

So I'm trying to display `info` data on `DataTable` and I got an error `info[0].slice` is not a function.

So I tried to comment `info[0].slice` this out . then it works but I can't get the `column.label` when i uncomment `info[0].slice` after i upload a file.

I don't know what happens behind it so i can't figure out .

So How can i make `columns` work ??

my code is like this :

```js
  const [info, setInfo] = useState([{}]);
  const handleOnDrop = droppedItems => {
    const infos = droppedItems.map(item => item.data);

    setInfo([...infos]);
  };
```

```js
const DataTable = ({ info }) => {
  // const columns = []; //this is what i was trying to do to make columns work afterwards.

  const columns = info[0]
    .slice(undefined)
    .map(inf => [{ id: inf, label: inf, minWidth: 170, align: "left" }]);
```

```js
<TableRow>
              {columns.map(column => (
                <TableCell
                  key={column.id}
                  align={column.align}
                  style={{ minWidth: column.minWidth }}
                >
                  <select name="" id="">
                    <option value="3" selected>
              
                    </option>
                    <option value="0">x</option>
                    <option value="1">y</option>
                    <option value="2">label</option>
                    
                  </select>{" "}
                  <p>{column.label}</p>
                </TableCell>
```

this should be the results when it works !

[image]

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish with `slice(undefined)`?

Comment: I'm trying to get all Array from info[0] with `slice(undefined)`

Comment: what is `info[0]` before slice?

Comment: it is  `(4) ["age ", "name", "phone", "city"]`  that is from a csv file (it's console results)

Comment: I should get the array from random data so i tried to do it like that

Comment: oh i didn't have to `slice(undefined)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see in your code - `info` is an array of objects.

Therefore `info[0]` is an object (not an array) and it doesn't have a splice method.

I'm not sure what's the purpose of `slice(undefined)` in your code. Could you please explain?

I would suggest you create a Minimal Working Sample, which reproduces your issue in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/boilerplate/react-jsx). This will make it easier for us to help you out.

Comment: I'm trying to get all Array from info[0] with slice(undefined) to get all the Array from uploaded csv file .